# Is there a way to color one specific variable from a group using a different color in ggplot2/R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to draw a specific variable (row) in a different color to make it stand out.
Currently my code runs as follows:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x= Timepoint, y = Test)) + 
geom_line(aes(group=patientID, color = PatientID)) +
facet_grid(~ DoseGrpDay0_D22) +
theme_bw()
```

Each dose group contains 10 patients and `ggplot` is assigning a decent rainbow color scheme to each patient. I like the color scheme and would like to keep it. However, I would like to superimpose a  black line for a specific patient 4,005 to make it stand out from the rest.

Comment: Try using pattern in aes and assign a pattern to patient 4005 alone

Comment: Thank you for your response. How do I assign a pattern to a specific value?

Comment: just add this at the end: geom_line(data =df[df$patientID==4005,], aes(group=patientID), color = "black")

Comment: A quicker way would be to simply change `color = patientID` to `color = patientID == 4005`. This creates a logical yes/no value that will automatically be colored categorically.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to explore `gghighlight` e.g.:

```r
require(gghighlight)
ggplot(df, aes(x= Timepoint, y = Test)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group=patientID, color = PatientID)) +
  facet_grid(~ DoseGrpDay0_D22) +
  gghighlight(PatientID == 4005) +
  theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the subset() function to create a df just has for the specific patient and use geom_point(data = patient4005, color = "black") to it.